# Accuracy of solutions of system of multivariable polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Theory of Gröbner basis has significant implications in many branches of Mathematics and Science. 
In particular, Gröbner basis are used to solve systems of multivariable polynomials that appears in different branches of Mathematics or Science.

For a solvable system of multivariable polynomials, there exists a univariant polynomials (i.e., polynomials in one unknown $x_1$) in the Gröbner basis. The first step to solve the system is to solve that univariant polynomials.
Due to the fact that degree $\ge 5$ univariant polynomials cannot be solved in terms of radicals, the computed roots of that univariant polynomials must be an approximation of the actual roots. Then the approximated roots are substituted back to the system to get another univariant polynomial in some other unknown $x_2$. In other words, we will get an approximation of actual roots of the approximation of the univariant polynomial in $x_2$. The process repeats until we get all the approximations of the solutions of the system.

> How can we know the approximations of solutions are small enough to make mathematical/ scientific conclusion? For example, can we get an approximation of the solution such that the error between the approximation and the actual solution are $<10^{-16}$?

Currently, I am using wxmaxima to compute the Gröbner basis. 
For some cases, I know $x_i=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ for some $i$, but the wxmaxima gives me an approximation with error of order $10^{-7}$.

> How can I improve the approximation so that the error is $<10^{-16}$ and how can I know the error for other $x_j$ in general?

Comment: There are algorithms to find the roots of univariate polynomials with guaranteed precision, see the MPSolve software: https://numpi.dm.unipi.it/software/mpsolve This does not answer your question though, since you also want to compute $x_2,x_3 \ldots$. A naïve approach is to compute the univariate polynomials wrt each $x_1,x_2,x_3 \ldots$, compute the approximate roots of those, and then decide which tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ satisfy your system of equations.

Comment: Very interesting question: a subtly related one was posted as a comment to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302437/is-there-an-analytic-way-of-solving-univariate-polynomial-equations-in-general/3302795#3302795) last summer by @semiclassical. He asked how it is possible to recover the exact radical solutions to a given univariate polynomial equation from the general algorithm, and this in turn is equivalent to ask how to recover a well defined and fast converging algorithm to a given root from a general one.

Comment: The Arb library in Sage can compute roots of approximate polynomials (that is, polynomials whose coefficients are complex *balls*). The output should be balls guaranteed to contain the roots. So you could apply root-finding to your approximate polynomial in $x_2$, and so on. See http://arblib.org/acb_poly.html#root-finding for more information.

Comment: The numerical accuracy of symbolic elimination methods generally doesn't scale well with the number of variables or degrees. See "Numerical instability of resultant methods" by Noferini and Townsend for a striking result along these lines. If you want control over the accuracy, you are probably better off using a global method for multivariate solving (eg. homotopy continuation if you want all solutions) and polishing roots with Newton. There are various theorems about how to check you are with $\epsilon $ of a true solution by looking at the Newton step and related quantities.