# Using rational univariate representation to obtain approximated solution of the system of multivariable polynomials with error $<10^{-16}$

Tags: polynomials, na.numerical-analysis

This post is a follow up question of my [previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353294/accuracy-of-solutions-of-system-of-multivariable-polynomials) (**Accuracy of solutions of system of multivariable polynomials**).

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations#Rational_univariate_representation) about *Rational univariate representation* (RUR):

Consider a zero-dimensional system of polynomials in variable $x_i$ for $1\le i\le n$.
Then we can express $x_i$ in terms of rational function of a root of some
univariate polynomial. More precisely:

A RUR of a zero-dimensional system consists in a linear combination $x_0$ of the variables, called separating variable, and a system of equations

\begin{cases}h(x_{0})=0\\x_{1}=g_{1}(x_{0})/g_{0}(x_{0})\\\quad \vdots \\x_{n}=g_{n}(x_{0})/g_{0}(x_{0}),\end{cases}
where $h$ is a univariate polynomial of degree $D$ and $g_0, \cdots, g_n$ are univariate polynomials of degree less than $D$.

For zero-dimensional systems, the RUR allows retrieval of the numeric values of the solutions by solving a single univariate polynomial and substituting them in rational functions. This allows production of certified approximations of the solutions to any given precision.

For more details about RUR, see this paper: [**Solving Zero-dimensional Polynomial Systems through the Rational Univariate Representation---Fabrice Rouillier**.](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00073264/document)

Moreover, MPSolve can compute the roots of univariate polynomials with guaranteed precision (Thanks to comment of François Brunault). So, one can approximate $x_0$ to any precision.

> However, I still do not know how to approximate $x_i$ to any precision.

Then I find out a paper

**A NEW ALGORITHM FOR REAL ROOTS OF A ZERO-DIMENSIONAL SYSTEM BY A LINEAR SEPARATING MAP---YUJI KONDOH, TOMOKATSU SAITO and TAKU TAKESHIMA**

about how to approximate $x_i$ to any precision. But it does not explicitly mention how.

According to the paper, it mentioned that[image]

> What is the **necessary procedure** that is equivalent to determine the sign of a algebraic number mentioned in the last sentence, in order to make sure one can get all the approximated solutions with error $<10^{-16}$?
>
> Are there any shortcut to ensure the errors involved in the approximated solution of the original zero-dimensional system are $<10^{-16}$?

Comment: Using interval arithmetic will solve your problem.
Have a look at the documentation [here](https://fr.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=RootFinding%2fIsolate).